# Third (3rd) Click Logout in FreakAuth

Tags: codeigniter

I've installed the FreakAuth Lite library for CodeIgniter (http://www.4webby.com/freakauth/). Everything is working nicely (logging in/out), but I have one problem. On the third page request after a user has logged in, the user is automatically logged out. This happens if you simply refresh the page three times, or click through to 3 separate pages. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, too, encountered that problem this evening.  After some searching around, I found that this guy, Kaga.Zepp, over on the [CodeIgniter forums](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/56647/P430/#530931) suggested removing the `'session'` 
library from `$autoload['libraries']` in `autoload.php`.  That seemed to do the trick for me, too.

I didn't poke around to try to figure out *why* exactly, but there you go.

Hope it works for you as well.